# .hover not working when sounded by other .hover elements

Tags: css

so I'm working on my second website and ran into a problem, I have png pictures that are supposed to have .hover effects. On their own they work as intended but as soon as I add a specific picture the other stop working, b.png/Asia and d.png/north America when I add them a.png/Europe and c.png/Africa s .hover stops working and i cant tell what the problem is.

I think the problem is the positioning or the sizing of the pngs. thats the entire script

```css
/** - - > Containers **/
  
  .container {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: -270px;
  }
  
  .container1 {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  
  .container2 {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 480px;
    left: -270px;
  }
  
  .container3 {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: -1000px;
  }
  
  .container4 {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left: 550px;
  }
  
  .container5 {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 165px;
    left: -280px;
  }
  
  .container6 {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 570px;
    left: -775px;
  }
  /** - - > End of Containers **/
  /** - - > Boxes **/
  
  .box,
  .box1,
  .box2,
  .box3,
  .box4,
  .box6 {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: .3s;
  }
  
  .box5 {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: .3s;
  }
  
  .box:hover,
  .box1:hover,
  .box2:hover,
  .box3:hover,
  .box4:hover,
  .box5:hover,
  .box6:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .box img,
  .box1 img,
  .box2 img,
  .box3 img,
  .box4 img,
  .box5 img,
  .box6 img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  /** - - > End of Boxes **/
  /** - - > Images **/
  
  .image {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
  }
  
  .image1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
  }
  
  .image2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
  }
  
  .image3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 680px;
  }
  
  .image4 {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
  }
  
  .image5 {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
  }
  
  .image6 {
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
  }
  
  .image__img,
  .image__img1,
  .image__img2,
  .image__img3,
  .image__img4,
  .image__img5,
  .image__img6 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .image__title,
  .image__title1,
  .image__title2,
  .image__title3,
  .image__title4,
  .image__title5,
  .image__title6 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-wight: bold;
  }
  /** - - >End of Images **/
  /** - - >Image Overlays **/
  
  .image__overlay,
  .image__overlay1,
  .image__overlay2,
  .image__overlay3,
  .image__overlay4,
  .image__overlay5,
  .image__overlay6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0, );
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
  }
  
  .image__overlay>*,
  .image__overlay1>*,
  .image__overlay2>*,
  .image__overlay3>*,
  .image__overlay4>*,
  .image__overlay5>*,
  .image__overlay6>* {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: transform 0.25s;
  }
  
  .image__overlay:hover>*,
  .image__overlay1:hover>*,
  .image__overlay2:hover>*,
  .image__overlay3:hover>*,
  .image__overlay4:hover>*,
  .image__overlay5:hover>*,
  .image__overlay6:hover>* {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .image__overlay:hover,
  .image__overlay1:hover,
  .image__overlay2:hover,
  .image__overlay3:hover,
  .image__overlay4:hover,
  .image__overlay5:hover,
  .image__overlay6:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /** - - >End of Image Overlays **/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-devicce-width, initial-scale=0.67">
</head>

<body>

  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="image__img" src="a.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay">
            <div class="image__title">Europa
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="box1">
        <div class="image1">
          <img class="image__img1" src="b.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay1">
            <div class="image__title1">Asien
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="image2">
          <img class="image__img2" src="c.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay2">
            <div class="image__title2">Africa
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="box3">
        <div class="image3">
          <img class="image__img3" src="d.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay3">
            <div class="image__title3">Nord America
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container4">
      <div class="box4">
        <div class="image4">
          <img class="image__img4" src="f.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay4">
            <div class="image__title4">Australien
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container6">
      <div class="box6">
        <div class="image6">
          <img class="image__img6" src="r.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay6">
            <div class="image__title6">Süd America
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, please take a look at the answer and test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a sizing issue.
I reduced the percentage of containers sizes to 50%.  Now all are working.

The containers are marked with red thick borders and dark gray background color.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-devicce-width, initial-scale=0.67">
</head>

<body>

  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="image__img" src="a.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay">
            <div class="image__title">Europa
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="box1">
        <div class="image1">
          <img class="image__img1" src="b.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay1">
            <div class="image__title1">Asien
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="image2">
          <img class="image__img2" src="c.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay2">
            <div class="image__title2">Africa
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="box3">
        <div class="image3">
          <img class="image__img3" src="d.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay3">
            <div class="image__title3">Nord America
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container4">
      <div class="box4">
        <div class="image4">
          <img class="image__img4" src="f.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay4">
            <div class="image__title4">Australien
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href=" ">
    <div class="container6">
      <div class="box6">
        <div class="image6">
          <img class="image__img6" src="r.png" alt="europa">
          <div class="image__overlay6">
            <div class="image__title6">Süd America
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>


<style>
  /** - - > Containers **/
  
  .container {
    border: 5px solid crimson;
    background: darkgray;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: -70px;
  }
  
  .container1 {
    border: 5px solid crimson;
    background: darkgray;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  
  .container2 {
    border: 5px solid crimson;
    background: darkgray;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 480px;
    left: -70px;
  }
  
  .container3 {
    border: 5px solid crimson;
    background: darkgray;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  
  .container4 {
    border: 5px solid crimson;
    background: darkgray;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left: 550px;
  }
  
  .container5 {
    border: 5px solid crimson;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 165px;
    left: -80px;
  }
  
  .container6 {
    border: 5px solid crimson;
    background: darkgray;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 570px;
    left: -75px;
  }
  /** - - > End of Containers **/
  /** - - > Boxes **/
  
  .box,
  .box1,
  .box2,
  .box3,
  .box4,
  .box6 {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: .3s;
  }
  
  .box5 {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: .3s;
  }
  
  .box:hover,
  .box1:hover,
  .box2:hover,
  .box3:hover,
  .box4:hover,
  .box5:hover,
  .box6:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .box img,
  .box1 img,
  .box2 img,
  .box3 img,
  .box4 img,
  .box5 img,
  .box6 img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  /** - - > End of Boxes **/
  /** - - > Images **/
  
  .image {
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
  }
  
  .image1 {
    background-color: lightpink;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;

  }
  
  .image2 {
    background-color: gold;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
  }
  
  .image3 {
    background-color: hotpink;
    position: relative;
    width: 680px;
  }
  
  .image4 {
    background-color: crimson;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
  }
  
  .image5 {
    background-color: ;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
  }
  
  .image6 {
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
  }
  
  .image__img,
  .image__img1,
  .image__img2,
  .image__img3,
  .image__img4,
  .image__img5,
  .image__img6 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .image__title,
  .image__title1,
  .image__title2,
  .image__title3,
  .image__title4,
  .image__title5,
  .image__title6 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-wight: bold;
  }
  /** - - >End of Images **/
  /** - - >Image Overlays **/
  
  .image__overlay,
  .image__overlay1,
  .image__overlay2,
  .image__overlay3,
  .image__overlay4,
  .image__overlay5,
  .image__overlay6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0, );
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
  }
  
  .image__overlay>*,
  .image__overlay1>*,
  .image__overlay2>*,
  .image__overlay3>*,
  .image__overlay4>*,
  .image__overlay5>*,
  .image__overlay6>* {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: transform 0.25s;
  }
  
  .image__overlay:hover>*,
  .image__overlay1:hover>*,
  .image__overlay2:hover>*,
  .image__overlay3:hover>*,
  .image__overlay4:hover>*,
  .image__overlay5:hover>*,
  .image__overlay6:hover>* {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .image__overlay:hover,
  .image__overlay1:hover,
  .image__overlay2:hover,
  .image__overlay3:hover,
  .image__overlay4:hover,
  .image__overlay5:hover,
  .image__overlay6:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /** - - >End of Image Overlays **/
</style>
```